# Asrestore : secondary indexes get deleted when already existing

Tags: aerospike

When restoring a backup of a cluster (3.8.2.3) into the same cluster, **secondary indexes get deleted** :

`show indexes Namespace`
gives 36 rows

```
cat Backup-Namespace.abs.gz | gunzip | asrestore --input-file - --no-records
```

`show indexes Namespace`
gives 0 rows

And if I restore once again with the same command
 `show indexes Namespace`
gives 36 rows

Same result for the option `--replace`, `--unique`

It works for `--no-generation` option, but as I would like the the lastest data, I don't want to use this option.

Note that the backup was created with :

```
asbackup --no-udfs --priority 1 --namespace Namespace --output-file -
```

To solve this problem I create indexes by hands where there are new ones, and I use `--no-indexes` for `asrestore` to update my data.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: please share the command you use to backup the file.  Also please share whether the index definitions are in the backup file (should be relatively human readable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing things right. This is an issue with the current asrestore tool. The asrestore tool first drops the indices from the backup using the C client's asynchronous API and doesn't wait for completion before attempting to re-create those same indices. This will cause the re-creation to often fail (since those indices still exist and are still being deleted).

Using the --wait option on the restore should help. And keep an eye for Jira TOOLS-608 in a soon to come Tools package release for some enhancements regarding this odd behavior.

Comment: I try `--wait` and `--indexes-last` and got the same results :/

Comment: Looks like the commit made it to the master branch. If you are comfortable, you can try taking the latest from the git repo: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-tools-backup/commits/master